# How to get access new sheet, created by adding a new form to spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

Im quite new to this thing and never had to post a question before.
Here is the situation :
I want to copy the same form over and over to the same spreadsheet('memoSs'). (original form being 'formFileSample').

I am trying to access the sheet linked to that newly added form. (form added using .setDestination()

Unfortunately that sheet is missing from the array returned by '.getSheets'!

Even though it appears in the spreadsheet 'memoSs' (checked by opening it)

I hope it is understandable with the script below.
any chance somebody might have a way in doing so?

```
function updateOfMemoSs() {
  var memoId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  var Interface = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Interface');
  var memoSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(memoId);
  var formFileSample = DriveApp.getFileById(memoSs.getSheetByName('Sample (Source)').getFormUrl().match(/[-\w]{25,}/));

  var sheetsToCopy = setInstrList();  //sets a list of names for the sheets to be created
                                      //looks like [['xxx'],['xx'],['x']]
  for(var i in sheetsToCopy){
    var newFormId = formFileSample.makeCopy('memo '+sheetsToCopy[i][0]).getId();
    var newForm = FormApp.openById(newFormId).setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, memoId);

//    var memoSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(memoId); //didnt work

    var sheets = memoSs.getSheets().filter(sheet => sheet.getFormUrl()); //sets a list of linked sheets
    Logger.log('formIds = ');
    for(var j in sheets){
      Logger.log(sheets[j].getName());
      Logger.log(sheets[j].getFormUrl().match(/[-\w]{25,}/));
   }//returns a list that does not include the linked sheet created earlier.(even though it appears in spreadsheet)
/*  for(var j in sheets){
      var sheet = sheets[j];
      if(sheet.getFormUrl().match(/[-\w]{25,}/) == newFormId){
        var newSheet = sheet;         //therefore I never find a match for newFormId
      }
    }*/
  }
//   Logger.log('newSheet = ');
//    Logger.log(newSheet.getName());
}
```

Comment: I think getSheets() returns all of the sheets.

Comment: It is also my understanding of getSheets(). However in this case it seems not to do so. All I want is to be able to name the linked sheet created by using 'FormApp.openById(newFormId).setDestination(//)'

Comment: Well try removing all of the linking from getSheets() and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cooper for considering the question.
It seems i haven't been patient enough in my research as the answer had already been posted in StackOverFlow : '[getSheets() Google Apps Script multiple calls issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819066/getsheets-google-apps-script-multiple-calls-issue)'
Somehow after creating a sheet.The following should be called before calling getSheets() :
`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`